# How to properly call rtlunwind from within an x86_64 windows exception handler

Tags: c, windows

I'm trying to implement a win64 exception personality and can't find much documentation on the subject.

I've already got a working win32 version but the win64 one crashes on `rtlunwind` (access violation) in the "catch" part of a win64 exception handler, to unwind to the catch handler frame and continuation:

```
int ExceptionHandler(EXCEPTION_RECORD arec, uint64_t EstablisherFrame, PCONTEXT context, PDISPATCHER_CONTEXT dispatcher)
{
  if (0 == (arec->ExceptionFlags & ( rtl.EXCEPTION_UNWINDING | rtl.EXCEPTION_EXIT_UNWIND))) 
  {
     // check if this is a catch supported
     rtl.RtlUnwindEx(EstablisherFrame, NULL, arec, NULL, context, dispatcher->HistoryTable);
     // call catch & jump to continuation
  }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to find the parameters to `RtlUnwind`/`RtlUnwindEx` for a given catch.

Can anyone point me to information on what I can try or a sample implementation of seh for win64?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out this can be done by passing a new exception object to rtlUnwind with a CallCatch method as first info parameter, with STATUS_UNWIND_CONSOLIDATE as code. This will unwind the whole thing (retriggering the personality for any cleanup/finally)

```
 EXCEPTION_RECORD EH;
  EH.ExceptionCode = STATUS_UNWIND_CONSOLIDATE;
  EH.ExceptionFlags = EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE;
  EH.NumberParameters = 4;
  EH.ExceptionInformation[0] = (ULONG)CallCatch;
  EH.ExceptionInformation[1] = EstFrame;
  EH.ExceptionInformation[2] = dispatcher->ImageBase + aHandler->Handler;
  EH.ExceptionInformation[3] = aCatch->TryLow;
rtl.RtlUnwindEx(estFrame, dispatcher->ControlPc, @EH, NULL, Context, dispatcher->HistoryTable);
```

Call catch should take a function with EXCEPTION_RECORD* as parameter, call the actual catch and returning the continuation address for this catch.