How to fill EXCEPTION_RECORD properly for a RtlUnwindEx call?
I am trying to manually handle a C++ exception ,caused by dynamically loaded code, through a VEH handler.At first I capture the exception with VEH then perform a stackwalk then call the __c_specific_handler to see if there is an actual handler and at last I need to make a call to RtlUnwindEx to actually call the catch callback. Reading at Skywing's study on X64 exception handling (http://www.nynaeve.net/?p=110) I find this:

Consolidation unwinds are a special form of unwind that is indicated to RtlUnwindEx with a special exception code, STATUS_UNWIND_CONSOLIDATE.
This exception code changes RtlUnwindEx’s behavior slightly; it suppresses the behavior of substituting the
TargetIp argument to RtlUnwindEx with the unwound context’s Rip value.
Make a local copy of the passed-in context record.
Treating ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation[0] as a callback function, this callback function is called (given a single argument pointing to the ExceptionRecord provided to RtlRestoreContext).
The return address of the callback function is treated as a new Rip value to place in the context that is about to be restored.
The context is restored as normal after the Rip value is updated based on the callback’s decision.
The callback routine pointed to by ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation[0] has the following signature:
Returns a new RIP value to be used in the restored context.
typedef ULONG64 (* PFRAME_CONSOLIDATON_ROUTINE)(
__in PEXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionRecord
);
Frame consolidation unwinds are typically used in conjunction with C++ try/catch/throw support.

This is my attempt to do it (this is just the last part inside VEH handler):
  auto language_handler = RtlVirtualUnwind(UNW_FLAG_EHANDLER, imagebase, (DWORD64)frames[i], lookup, &context, &handler_data, &establisher_frame, NULL);

  DISPATCHER_CONTEXT new_dc = {};
  new_dc.ControlPc = (DWORD64)frames[i];
  new_dc.ImageBase = imagebase;
  new_dc.FunctionEntry = lookup;
  new_dc.EstablisherFrame = establisher_frame;
  new_dc.TargetIp = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&lookup);
  new_dc.ContextRecord = ex->ContextRecord;
  new_dc.LanguageHandler = language_handler;
  new_dc.HandlerData = handler_data;
  DISPATCHER_CONTEXT new_dcc = {};
  auto result = language_handler(ex->ExceptionRecord, (void*)establisher_frame, ex->ContextRecord, &new_dc);
  
  
 if (result == EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {
     
     EXCEPTION_RECORD EH;
     EH.ExceptionCode = STATUS_UNWIND_CONSOLIDATE;
     EH.ExceptionFlags = EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE;
     EH.NumberParameters = 1;
     EH.ExceptionInformation[0] = ;
     
    RtlUnwindEx((void*)establisher_frame, frames[i],&EH,NULL,ex->ContextRecord,NULL);
    return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
}

My problem is that I am unable to find out what this parameter EH.ExceptionInformation[0] = ;
should contain.
If someone has tried this in the past, let me know

An array of additional arguments that describe the exception.  Usually the array elements are undefined. It's ok just set it to 0.

@Torrecto-MSFT I tried it but the catch filter isn't called

Pass a new exception object to rtlUnwind with a CallCatch method as first info parameter. EXCEPTION_RECORD EH;   EH.ExceptionCode = STATUS_UNWIND_CONSOLIDATE;   EH.ExceptionFlags = EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE;   EH.NumberParameters = 4;   EH.ExceptionInformation[0] = (ULONG)CallCatch;   EH.ExceptionInformation[1] = EstFrame;   EH.ExceptionInformation[2] = dispatcher->ImageBase + aHandler->Handler;   EH.ExceptionInformation[3] = aCatch->TryLow; rtl.RtlUnwindEx(estFrame, dispatcher->ControlPc, @EH, NULL, Context, dispatcher->HistoryTable);

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39731046/how-to-properly-call-rtlunwind-from-within-an-x86-64-windows-exception-handler and this link: https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/59d22905af41a9131e4a96ef767fc9fbaa4d3a0f/system/lib/libunwind/src/Unwind-seh.cpp#L75

@Torrecto-MSFT I actually saw that question, But he doesn't specify what exactly he passes to ExceptionInformation[]. That callcatch is the address of the original catch statement?And what are the other 3 arguments?

@Torrecto-MSFT btw this is the full code of the loader if you wanna try it: https://pastebin.com/xBE1rwc6

Use EHRegistrationNode, DispatcherContext, etc from <ehdata.h>.
#include<excpt.h>
#include<ehdata.h>

I used the EHRegistrationNode struct so that ExceptionInformation's array used its callbacks. I added comments to the code.
EHRegistrationNode* pFrame{};            // Unwind up to (but not including) this frame
                    EHExceptionRecord* pExcept{};           // The exception that initiated this unwind
                    CONTEXT* pContext{};          // Context info for current exception
                    EHRegistrationNode* pEstablisher{};
                    void* Handler{};
                    __ehstate_t         TargetUnwindState{};
                    FuncInfo* pFuncInfo{};
                    DispatcherContext* pDC{};
                    BOOLEAN             recursive{};

                    static const EXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionTemplate = // A generic exception record
                    {
                        STATUS_UNWIND_CONSOLIDATE,         // STATUS_UNWIND_CONSOLIDATE
                        EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE,          // Exception flags (we don't do resume)
                        nullptr,                           // Additional record (none)
                        nullptr,                           // Address of exception (OS fills in)
                        15,                                // Number of parameters
                        {   EH_MAGIC_NUMBER1,              // Our version control magic number
                            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
                        }                                  // pThrowInfo
                    };

                    DISPATCHER_CONTEXT new_dc = {};
                    new_dc.ControlPc = (DWORD64)frames[i];
                    new_dc.ImageBase = imagebase;
                    new_dc.FunctionEntry = lookup;
                    new_dc.EstablisherFrame = establisher_frame;
                    new_dc.TargetIp = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&lookup);
                    new_dc.ContextRecord = ex->ContextRecord;
                    new_dc.LanguageHandler = language_handler;
                    new_dc.HandlerData = handler_data;

                    auto result = language_handler(ex->ExceptionRecord, (void*)establisher_frame, ex->ContextRecord, &new_dc);
                    /////CALL CATCH FILTER?
                    if (result == EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {

                        EXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionRecord = ExceptionTemplate;
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[0] = 0;
                        // Address of call back function
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[1] = (ULONG_PTR)pEstablisher;
                        // Used by callback funciton
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[2] = (ULONG_PTR)Handler;
                        // Used by callback function to call catch block
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[3] = (ULONG_PTR)TargetUnwindState;
                        // Used by CxxFrameHandler to unwind to target_state
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[4] = (ULONG_PTR)pContext;
                        // used to set pCurrentExContext in callback function
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[5] = (ULONG_PTR)pFuncInfo;
                        // Used in callback function to set state on stack to -2
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[6] = (ULONG_PTR)pExcept;
                        // Used for passing current Exception
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[7] = (ULONG_PTR)recursive;
                        // Used for translated Exceptions
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[8] = EH_MAGIC_NUMBER1;
                        // Used in __InternalCxxFrameHandler to detected if it's being
                        // called from _UnwindNestedFrames.

                        RtlUnwindEx((void*)pFrame, (void*)pDC->ControlPc, &ExceptionRecord, NULL, ex->ContextRecord, (PUNWIND_HISTORY_TABLE)pDC->HistoryTable);
                        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;

Also, you need to know sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader is not initialized, so the memory location it points to is unknown, which will inevitably cause errors like read violation.
So I modified it to this in peLoader:
PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 sourceNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS64)malloc(sizeof(*sourceNtHeaders));
IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 sourceSize = (sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader);
SIZE_T szsz = sizeof(sourceSize.ImageBase);

auto imgBaseAt = (void*)sourceSize.ImageBase;//initialized
auto imgSize = sourceSize.SizeOfImage;
bool relocOk = !!sourceSize.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].VirtualAddress;

Now the function is online.

Remeber to modify your file in fopen. Here is the full code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include<excpt.h>
#include<ehdata.h>
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
#define getNtHdr(buf) ((IMAGE_NT_HEADERS *)((size_t)buf + ((IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *)buf)->e_lfanew))
#define getSectionArr(buf) ((IMAGE_SECTION_HEADER *)((size_t)buf + ((IMAGE_DOS_HEADER *)buf)->e_lfanew + sizeof(IMAGE_NT_HEADERS)))


typedef enum _UNWIND_OP_CODES {
    UWOP_PUSH_NONVOL = 0, /* info == register number */
    UWOP_ALLOC_LARGE,     /* no info, alloc size in next 2 slots */
    UWOP_ALLOC_SMALL,     /* info == size of allocation / 8 - 1 */
    UWOP_SET_FPREG,       /* no info, FP = RSP + UNWIND_INFO.FPRegOffset*16 */
    UWOP_SAVE_NONVOL,     /* info == register number, offset in next slot */
    UWOP_SAVE_NONVOL_FAR, /* info == register number, offset in next 2 slots */
    UWOP_SAVE_XMM128 = 8, /* info == XMM reg number, offset in next slot */
    UWOP_SAVE_XMM128_FAR, /* info == XMM reg number, offset in next 2 slots */
    UWOP_PUSH_MACHFRAME   /* info == 0: no error-code, 1: error-code */
} UNWIND_CODE_OPS;

typedef unsigned char UBYTE;



#define UNW_FLAG_EHANDLER  0x01
#define UNW_FLAG_UHANDLER  0x02
#define UNW_FLAG_CHAININFO 0x04




bool readBinFile(const char fileName[], char** bufPtr, size_t& length)
{
    if (FILE* fp = fopen("rb.txt", "r"))
    {
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
        length = ftell(fp);
        *bufPtr = (char*)malloc(length + 1);
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        fread(*bufPtr, sizeof(char), length, fp);
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

void fixIat(char* peImage)
{
    auto dir_ImportTable = getNtHdr(peImage)->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_IMPORT];
    auto impModuleList = (IMAGE_IMPORT_DESCRIPTOR*)&peImage[dir_ImportTable.VirtualAddress];
    for (HMODULE currMod; impModuleList->Name; impModuleList++)
    {
        printf("\timport module : %s\n", &peImage[impModuleList->Name]);
        currMod = LoadLibraryA(&peImage[impModuleList->Name]);

        auto arr_callVia = (IMAGE_THUNK_DATA*)&peImage[impModuleList->FirstThunk];
        for (int count = 0; arr_callVia->u1.Function; count++, arr_callVia++)
        {
            auto curr_impApi = (PIMAGE_IMPORT_BY_NAME)&peImage[arr_callVia->u1.Function];
            arr_callVia->u1.Function = (size_t)GetProcAddress(currMod, (char*)curr_impApi->Name);
            if (count < 5)
                printf("\t\t- fix imp_%s\n", curr_impApi->Name);
        }
    }
}

#define RELOC_32BIT_FIELD 0x03
#define RELOC_64BIT_FIELD 0x0A
typedef struct BASE_RELOCATION_ENTRY
{
    WORD Offset : 12;
    WORD Type : 4;
} entry;

void fixReloc(char* peImage)
{
    auto dir_RelocTable = getNtHdr(peImage)->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC];
    auto relocHdrBase = &peImage[dir_RelocTable.VirtualAddress];
    for (UINT hdrOffset = 0; hdrOffset < dir_RelocTable.Size;)
    {
        auto relocHdr = (IMAGE_BASE_RELOCATION*)&relocHdrBase[hdrOffset];
        entry* entryList = (entry*)((size_t)relocHdr + sizeof(*relocHdr));
        for (size_t i = 0; i < (relocHdr->SizeOfBlock - sizeof(*relocHdr)) / sizeof(entry); i++)
        {
            size_t rva_Where2Patch = relocHdr->VirtualAddress + entryList[i].Offset;
            if (entryList[i].Type == RELOC_32BIT_FIELD)
            {
                *(UINT32*)&peImage[rva_Where2Patch] -= (size_t)getNtHdr(peImage)->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;
                *(UINT32*)&peImage[rva_Where2Patch] += (size_t)peImage;
            }
            else if (entryList[i].Type == RELOC_64BIT_FIELD)
            {
                *(UINT64*)&peImage[rva_Where2Patch] -= (size_t)getNtHdr(peImage)->OptionalHeader.ImageBase;
                *(UINT64*)&peImage[rva_Where2Patch] += (size_t)peImage;
            }
        }
        hdrOffset += relocHdr->SizeOfBlock;
    }
}
char* basee = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char*));
int* sizee = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
void peLoader(char* exeData)
{
 

    PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS64 sourceNtHeaders = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS64)malloc(sizeof(*sourceNtHeaders));
    IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER64 sourceSize = (sourceNtHeaders->OptionalHeader);;
    SIZE_T szsz = sizeof(sourceSize.ImageBase);

    auto imgBaseAt = (void*)sourceSize.ImageBase;//initialized
    auto imgSize = sourceSize.SizeOfImage;
    bool relocOk = !!sourceSize.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_BASERELOC].VirtualAddress;
    *sizee = imgSize;
    char* peImage = (char*)VirtualAlloc(relocOk ? 0 : imgBaseAt, imgSize, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    basee = peImage;
    if (peImage)
    {
        printf("[v] exe file mapped @ %p\n", peImage);
        memcpy(peImage, exeData, getNtHdr(exeData)->OptionalHeader.SizeOfHeaders);
        for (int i = 0; i < getNtHdr(exeData)->FileHeader.NumberOfSections; i++)
        {
            auto curr_section = getSectionArr(exeData)[i];
            memcpy(
                &peImage[curr_section.VirtualAddress],
                &exeData[curr_section.PointerToRawData],
                curr_section.SizeOfRawData);
        }
        printf("[v] file mapping ok\n");

        fixIat(peImage);
        printf("[v] fix iat.\n");

        if (relocOk)
        {
            fixReloc(peImage);
            printf("[v] apply reloc.\n");
        }

        auto addrOfEntry = getNtHdr(exeData)->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;
        auto table = getNtHdr(peImage)->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION].VirtualAddress;
        auto tablesz = getNtHdr(peImage)->OptionalHeader.DataDirectory[IMAGE_DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXCEPTION].Size;

        RtlAddFunctionTable((RUNTIME_FUNCTION*)(table + basee), tablesz / sizeof(RUNTIME_FUNCTION), (DWORD64)peImage);

        printf("[v] invoke entry @ %p ...\n", &peImage[addrOfEntry]);
       ((void (*)()) & peImage[addrOfEntry])();
    }
    else
        printf("[x] alloc memory for exe @ %p failure.\n", imgBaseAt);
}
DWORD64 imagebase = NULL;

LONG handler(EXCEPTION_POINTERS* ex) {

    if (ex->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode == 0xE06D7363) {

        const int maxFrames = 100;
        void* frames[maxFrames];
        USHORT framesCaptured = RtlCaptureStackBackTrace(0, maxFrames, frames, nullptr);
        void* handler_data = NULL;
        uint64_t establisher_frame = NULL;
        CONTEXT  context;
        RtlCaptureContext(&context);


        for (USHORT i = 0; i < framesCaptured; ++i)
        {

            auto lookup = RtlLookupFunctionEntry((DWORD64)frames[i], &imagebase, NULL);



            UNWIND_INFO* ui = (UNWIND_INFO*)(imagebase + lookup->UnwindInfoAddress);


            if (ui->Flags & UNW_FLAG_EHANDLER || ui->Flags & UNW_FLAG_UHANDLER) {

                if ((DWORD64)imagebase < (DWORD64)GetModuleHandle(NULL)) {

                    auto language_handler = RtlVirtualUnwind(UNW_FLAG_EHANDLER, imagebase, (DWORD64)frames[i], lookup, &context, &handler_data, &establisher_frame, NULL);

                 
                    EHRegistrationNode* pFrame{};            // Unwind up to (but not including) this frame
                    EHExceptionRecord* pExcept{};           // The exception that initiated this unwind
                    CONTEXT* pContext{};          // Context info for current exception
                    EHRegistrationNode* pEstablisher{};
                    void* Handler{};
                    __ehstate_t         TargetUnwindState{};
                    FuncInfo* pFuncInfo{};
                    DispatcherContext* pDC{};
                    BOOLEAN             recursive{};

                    static const EXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionTemplate = // A generic exception record
                    {
                        STATUS_UNWIND_CONSOLIDATE,         // STATUS_UNWIND_CONSOLIDATE
                        EXCEPTION_NONCONTINUABLE,          // Exception flags (we don't do resume)
                        nullptr,                           // Additional record (none)
                        nullptr,                           // Address of exception (OS fills in)
                        15,                                // Number of parameters
                        {   EH_MAGIC_NUMBER1,              // Our version control magic number
                            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
                        }                                  // pThrowInfo
                    };

                    DISPATCHER_CONTEXT new_dc = {};
                    new_dc.ControlPc = (DWORD64)frames[i];
                    new_dc.ImageBase = imagebase;
                    new_dc.FunctionEntry = lookup;
                    new_dc.EstablisherFrame = establisher_frame;
                    new_dc.TargetIp = reinterpret_cast<uint64_t>(&lookup);
                    new_dc.ContextRecord = ex->ContextRecord;
                    new_dc.LanguageHandler = language_handler;
                    new_dc.HandlerData = handler_data;

                    auto result = language_handler(ex->ExceptionRecord, (void*)establisher_frame, ex->ContextRecord, &new_dc);
                    /////CALL CATCH FILTER?
                    if (result == EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER) {

                        EXCEPTION_RECORD ExceptionRecord = ExceptionTemplate;
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[0] = 0;
                        // Address of call back function
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[1] = (ULONG_PTR)pEstablisher;
                        // Used by callback funciton
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[2] = (ULONG_PTR)Handler;
                        // Used by callback function to call catch block
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[3] = (ULONG_PTR)TargetUnwindState;
                        // Used by CxxFrameHandler to unwind to target_state
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[4] = (ULONG_PTR)pContext;
                        // used to set pCurrentExContext in callback function
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[5] = (ULONG_PTR)pFuncInfo;
                        // Used in callback function to set state on stack to -2
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[6] = (ULONG_PTR)pExcept;
                        // Used for passing current Exception
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[7] = (ULONG_PTR)recursive;
                        // Used for translated Exceptions
                        ExceptionRecord.ExceptionInformation[8] = EH_MAGIC_NUMBER1;
                        // Used in __InternalCxxFrameHandler to detected if it's being
                        // called from _UnwindNestedFrames.

                        RtlUnwindEx((void*)pFrame, (void*)pDC->ControlPc, &ExceptionRecord, NULL, ex->ContextRecord, (PUNWIND_HISTORY_TABLE)pDC->HistoryTable);
                        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
                    }

                }


            }







        }

        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION;
    }
    return  EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;





}


int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    AddVectoredExceptionHandler(1, handler);
    char* exeBuf;
    size_t exeSize;
    readBinFile(argv[1], &exeBuf, exeSize);
    peLoader(exeBuf);

    return 0;
}


I appreciate your time and thank you very much.Now I tested your modified loader with this simple exe and It just breaks on runtime (both exes on release):                                                                                                                    #include 
#include <windows.h>
void excep() {
try {
int k = 11;
throw (k);
}
catch (int j) {
   
    std::cout << j;

}

}
int main() {
std::cout << "test";
excep();
return 0;

}

Also if i fill the ExceptionInformation[0] with the address of just a void function that just outputs a string  the rtlunwindex will call that. So I though that if I could get the catch statement's address I could just fill the ExceptionInformation[0] with that.I also found out that ex->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionInformation[1] (of the vector) contains the thrown object,but can't think a way that could help

@HasakissHaselioss Actually ExceptionInformation[0] use __CxxCallCatchBlock to fill. But I cannot write it.

yeah I thnk it just can't be functional.. thanks again:),the only thing I can't get is why the system can't handle the try/catch as it can handle _try/_except with just adding RtlAddFunctionTable

@HasakissHaselioss system can't handle the try/catch, like this?：try {     // STATE1 = 1        try {           // STATE2           // THROW         } catch (...) { // CatchB1           // STATE3           // RETHROW OR NEW THROW         }       } catch (...) { // CatchB2       }

I found this: https://github.com/d366/DarkMMap/blob/master/Process.cpp#L173 which I think does what I need but he follows a completely different method

@HasakissHaselioss Wow that's different. That's more like process hollowing. Well, glad to see you find a solution. You can make a answer and accept after 24hours.

well, I don't really understand what he is doing or why this works, but that's something I guess..
